# Excel VBA Vlookup second most recent data for a value

Tags: vba, excel

Currently working on an Excel worksheet with Vlookup. My reference table in Sheet 1 has a list of data along with its date, its name defined as ProjectEntry. For example:

```
-----------------------------------
| Project No | ID |  Service Date |
|------------|----|---------------|
|     01     | A1 |   10/12/17    |
|     02     | B2 |   13/12/17    |
|     01     | A1 |   14/12/17    |
|     03     | C3 |   14/12/17    |
|     01     | A1 |   16/12/17    |
-----------------------------------
```

Now my Vlookup in Sheet2 wants to lookup the second most recent date based on the ID to get the last service date. For example when I select ID = 01 , Vlookup = 14/12/17.

For the Vlookup formula I managed to get the first entered Service Date (10/12/17):

```
=VLOOKUP(I7,ProjectEntry[[#All],[ID]:[Service Date]],2,FALSE)
```

But I'm not sure how to get the 2nd most recent date for A1. What should I add to the formula to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of seeking the *"second-to-last match"* we could instead look for the *"second highest match"*, in which case an **array formula** using the `LARGE` function will return what you need.

If your example data is arranged in `A2:C6` like this:

[image: sample data]

then you could use this array formula to return the "2nd highest date" where the `ID = A1` :

```
=LARGE(IF($B$2:$B$6="A1",$C$2:$C$6),2)
```

Your question said you need to look for `ID = 01` but those are two different columns.  If you instead need to look for `Project No = 01" then your array formula would be :

```
=LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$6="01",$C$2:$C$6),2)
```

...that's assuming that `Project No` is stored as **text**.  If it's actually a number (formatted with a leading zero) then you would use :

```
=LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$6=1,$C$2:$C$6),2).
```

---

**☆** Remember that ***since these are all ARRAY FORMULAS you need to specify that*** when entering the formulas; instead of using <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, finish entering the formula with:

> **<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>**

---

### EDIT:

To clarify whether this method will work, if the data is arranged like this:

[image: example2]

...which value should be returned for `ID = A1` (or `Project No = 1`)?

- second-to-**last**  (2016-12-17)
- second-most-**recent**?  (2014-12-17)

Comment: Well that depends on how the users use it. For all I know they may jump around here and there so I gotta be prepared for that.

Comment: These formulas require that the dates be "true" dates (meaning numeric, not strings). They will throw an error if there was no second-largest, such as Project No. 03 in the question's example.

Comment: @hjh93 - so an older date _could_ be entered after a newer one, correct?  Also to address Variatus's concern, I assume the dates are stored normally, not as text, correct?  (As in, do the example formulas I gave work so far?)

Comment: see my above [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47985541/8112776) (in my answer) to clarify what you need.

Comment: 2nd to most recent.

Comment: Perfect, in that case the formula I gave above will work.  (and you can forget what I said about the data having to be in ascending order.)

Comment: Ok. I tried and I works. But say I want to put it in VBA. How exactly do I do it? Just copy the array into VBA?

Comment: @hjh93 - What do you mean, "you want to put it in VBA", and why?  Either way, it's more than "just copying" it...  If it works fine, why the need to complicate it?